# Phone call codes by country mvc c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

`CultureInfo` and `RegionInfo` classes provide information about countries but I dont seem to find the call codes info and I need them for a dropdown list in a registration view.The typical Country Flag and +34 for example code for that country.

Can I find something like that or should I take a different approach to get them on the view?

Comment: Google for "libphonenumber".

Comment: But that is just a parser right ?A validator...I will put it to use anyways but i need the world coutries dropdown.

Comment: OK, so perhaps libphonenumber isn't providing you with this information but .NET surely isn't so you still need to find some 3rd party source for this information, be it a class library, if such a thing thus exists, or a list which you need to bake into your software.

Comment: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input . . .may be it is helpful.

Comment: This package contains the required informations https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Country